# Grabbing data from JSON using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Ok so I have a json output that looks like this:

```
{"Result" : [
              {
                "Id" : "5214",
                "ParentReasonId" : "0",
                "Description" : "Billing & Payment",
                "SysName" : "Billing & Payment",
                "SysCategory" : "Billing & Payment",
                "ClientId" : "924",
                "DispositionCount" : "6",
                "IsActive" : true,
                "ChildReasonCount" : "8",
                "Attributes" : [],
                "SortOrder" : "0",
                "CreatedBy" : null
              }
            ]
 }
```

And I would like to pull the data for id and description out of this.

```
    jQuery("#chained_child").cascade("#chained", {
    ajax: { url: 'Customhandler.ashx?List=MyList' },
        template: commonTemplate,
        match: commonMatch
    });

function commonTemplate(item) {
    return "<option Value='" + item.Result.Id + "'>" 
           + item.Result.Description + "</option>";
};
```

But for the life of me I can't get it to return the value I am looking for. I know this is something noobish but I am hitting a wall. Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't suppose it's the syntax error that's messing you up?

Comment: When I put alert(item.Result.Id) I get back undefined. So I'm not totally sure.

Comment: Is that JSON being returned as a string from somewhere?  Are you making sure that it has been eval'ed into an object?  Find out by alert(typeof item);

Answer (score 6):

If you examine your JSON string, your `Result` object is actually an array of size 1 containing an object, not just an object. You should remove the extra brackets or refer to your variable using:

```
item.Result[0].Id
```

In order to reference your variable using `item.Result.Id` you would need the following JSON string:

```
{
    "Result" :
    {
        "Id" : "5214",
        "ParentReasonId" : "0",
        "Description" : "Billing & Payment",
        "SysName" : "Billing & Payment",
        "SysCategory" : "Billing & Payment",
        "ClientId" : "924",
        "DispositionCount" : "6",
        "IsActive" : true,
        "ChildReasonCount" : "8",
        "Attributes" : [],
        "SortOrder" : "0",
        "CreatedBy" : null
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and got nowhere. I get the error item.Result is not defined? I know the data is coming across the wire, not sure what to make of it.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that has helped me immensely with JSON funkyness has been setting breakpoints in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), which let's you step through the resulting object, and view its structure.

Comment: This definately helped. It appears that the only thing item has within it is the url which is very strange.

Answer (score 1):

item.Result[0].Id works as Sebastian mentioned - however it only works if "item" is actually assigned a value. My guess is it's not.

In your commonTemplate function try doing console.log(item) and seeing what the result is.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see it on the [plugin page](http://dev.chayachronicles.com/jquery/cascade/index.html), the argument send to the template callback is an
**item** from the JSON response, which is an Array. Your JSON response is an Object. I guess you're not sending the correct JSON response. But take that with a grain of salt, as I've never used this plugin.

Anyway, if I'm right, you're response should be:

```
[
    {
        "Result" :
        {
            "Id" : "5214",
            "ParentReasonId" : "0",
            "Description" : "Billing & Payment",
            "SysName" : "Billing & Payment",
            "SysCategory" : "Billing & Payment",
            "ClientId" : "924",
            "DispositionCount" : "6",
            "IsActive" : true,
            "ChildReasonCount" : "8",
            "Attributes" : [],
            "SortOrder" : "0",
            "CreatedBy" : null
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ionut G. Stan's answer is correct. Your json output is not the correct format for the cascade plugin.

If you don't want to change your json, you can use the `dataFilter` option in the `ajax` settings to augment the data.

I've set up a working demo here: http://jsbin.com/ebohe (editable via http://jsbin.com/ebohe/edit )

Here's the pertinent javascript:

```
$(function(){
  $('#chained_child').cascade(
    '#chained',
    {
      ajax: {
        url: 'Customhandler.ashx?List=MyList',
        dataFilter: extractResult
      },
      template: customTemplate,
      match: customMatch
    }
  );

  function extractResult(data) {
    return eval('(' + data + ')').Result;
  }

  function customTemplate(item) {
    return $('<option />')
      .val(item.Id)
      .text(item.Description);
  }

  function customMatch(selectedValue) {
    return this.ParentReasonId == selectedValue;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this JSON tutorial from IBM:

[Mastering Ajax, Part 10: Using JSON for data transfer](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ajaxintro10/index.html?S_TACT=105AGX08&S_CMP=EDU)